# Android, Renderscript, ScriptIntrinsicBlur, import libRSSuport.so and librsjni.so

Tags: android, eclipse, renderscript

I am developing an app which uses Canny Edge Detection. The most time consuming step here is the initial application of Gaussian blur (e.g. applying 11x11 kernel on 500k pics). In order to speed this up I want to use the ScriptIntrinsicBlur method of renderscript. I have set-up the code in Eclipse, included the latest BuildTools 22.0.1, as described e.g. on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#ide-setup. Import of renderscrip-v8.jar works, compilation works, but I don't manage to get it run, not even on my Samsung S5. The error is related to the missing import of libRSSupport.so and librsjni.so. I read dozens of threads on the topic, but didn't found a solution. I am at the point to give it up... (and consider using smaller picsize and kernels - at the cost of lower Quality)  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Just as I sidenote: I made a prototype in Java, there using the java.awt.image.ConvolveOp for gaussian blur. This one is VERY fast - but unfortunately not available in Android.

Comment: can't you use OpenCV to do that? Canny and GaussianBlur are a few milliseconds each

Comment: you are right, Miki, I will check that now. Anyway, I have a lot of sympathy for a Java-only implementation, since from what I read about Renderscript, it is not really reliable on some devices and I don't want to risk any problems. Technically I wonder, how openCV manages to reach such a speed. I wrote a simple blur algorithm in Android with nested for-loops through image-pixels and Kernel, that takes about 50 mio  (11x11x600x800) multiplications and additions for a gray-picture, and that takes 1s on my Samsung. Anyway, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the instructions from http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html (except updating the tools version numbers to the latest, which should be the default)? It sounds like you just added the .jar to your project manually, which is not going to be sufficient. The project options specified there ensure that all of the components are bundled as part of your APK.

Comment: I already added these 3 lines to the project properties in Eclipse, but this only creates an Import of the renderscript v8.jar, but not the libRSSupport.so and librsjni.so libraries - which are needed too for running renderscript. I see from the LogCat that this is the Problem and execution stops right at the ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create Statement. Also, I have some doubt, wheter I should change from Eclipse to Android Studio, as the former is not supported by Google anymore, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were on Eclipse. I believe they always needed to specify the .so libraries independently. You would probably be best off switching to Android Studio, since that is the only supported path going forward.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I must have been blind...Only now I realized that there is a already a GaussBlur Function provided by Android, named BlurMaskFilter. This one is absolutely sufficient for my purpose and rather fast. If anyone is interested I can post the short code here.

Comment: Addendum.... BlurMaskFilter just creates some blur around the edges of the image. So this cannot be used as a Gauss Filter for Images. Since I don't want to use Renderscript or any other libraries (such as OpenCV) that require additional libraries to be imported by the end user I am more than happy that I found this excellent article about the separability of the  Gauss Matrix: http://www.cb.uu.se/~cris/blog/index.php/archives/150.  I completely forgot about this nice Feature of the Gauss-Kernel, which, in essence reduces comptation effort from n^2 to 2n. I implement this now.

Comment: Just as an update. After trying 100 other things that did not bring the desired speed for the Gaussian Blur I finally moved from Eclipse to Android Studio. I must admit, I was rather sceptical. But...unbelievable! In the very first attempt the Renderscript worked without any problems! And its speed is just superb. More than happy!!!

Comment: I am glad to hear that everything is now working. Please let us know if anything in Android Studio causes trouble for you.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Now that I see what Renderscript can perform (and since I have a strong Background im Image processing) I would like to study Renderscript from scratch and write own scripts (e.g. for histogram equalisation, image registration etc.). But I didn't find a dedicated book in Amazon and the tutorials in the Internet just look at partial aspects. What material would you recommend to  study? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/java/tests has a good set of samples (look at ImageProcessing since you can leverage your existing knowledge/understanding there). We are also working on some improved documentation and tutorials, but I am not sure when those are going to be available.